# How would you add new column to a dataframe based on conditional math from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

Let me simplify this.

I have currency conversation key DataFrame, it has 2 columns. Currency and Spot FX Rate in USD.

```
currency    fx_rate
INR         0.013223
JPY         0.008653
MYR         0.239000
CNY         0.157300
HKD         0.128160
```

My 2nd DataFrame is

```
currency ID   amount outstanding
    INR 78waf 1000000000
    JPY 48waf 100000000000
    MYR 38waf 10000000
    CNY 28waf 1000000000
    HKD 18waf 10000000
```

How would I create a Fourth Column in my 2nd DF ("CONVERTED AMOUNT") based on Currency Key DataFrame? You would need to Multiple for the conversion (for INR: 0.013223 * 1000000000 = 13223000)

end goal:

```
currency ID   amount outstanding CONVERTED AMOUNT
    INR 78waf 1000000000         13223000
    JPY 48waf 100000000000       etc..
    MYR 38waf 10000000           ...
    CNY 28waf 1000000000         ...
    HKD 18waf 10000000           ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your two last dataframes seem to have more columns than they should.

Anyway, if I understand your problem correctly, I will probably just go like this:

```py
df["CONVERTED AMOUNT"] = df["amount"] * 0.013223
```

Comment: Sorry I poorly explained the problem. The First df is a lookup. You must match the currency type to the 2nd df , Then take the corresponding spot rate of that matched currency and multiply it by the amount outstanding in the 2nd df to genrated a new column in the 2nd df.

Comment: @Sumit No problem. So you just need to use `merge` on your dataframes and use `on` argument to define the common column.

Answer (score 1):

You could map "fx_rate" to "currency" column in `df2` and multiply with "amount_outstanding":

```
df2['converted_amount'] = df2['currency'].map(df1.set_index('currency')['fx_rate']) * df2['amount_outstanding']
```

You could also `set_index` with "currency" and multiply the amounts on matching currencies and `reset_index`:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('currency')
df2['converted_amount'] = df2['amount_outstanding'].mul(df1.set_index('currency')['fx_rate'])
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

Another options is to `merge` the DataFrames on "currency" and multiply the relevant columns:

```
merged = df2.merge(df1, on='currency')
merged['converted_amount'] = merged['amount_outstanding'] * merged['fx_rate']
out = merged.drop(columns=['fx_rate'])
```

Output:

```
  currency     ID  amount_outstanding  converted_amount
0      INR  78waf          1000000000        13223000.0
1      JPY  48waf        100000000000       865300000.0
2      MYR  38waf            10000000         2390000.0
3      CNY  28waf          1000000000       157300000.0
4      HKD  18waf            10000000         1281600.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.merge(df2, df1, how = 'left', on = 'currency')
df['converted_amount'] = df['amount_outstanding'] * df['fx_rate']
```